# ANOVA on IQ Study Involving Gender, Volume of Brain, and cross section of Corpus Callosum

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, manova

I've got a study and I'm trying to use ANOVA to determine how the variables are related to each other. Here's what the format of the data is:

```
SEX | IQ |  CC_SA (cm^2) | TOT_VOL (cm^3) |
M    102     7.99              1173
F    100     8.76              1079
.     .       .                 .
.     .       .                 .
.     .       .                 .
```

Since the "units" of IQ are different from the `Cross Section` of the Corpus Callosum, and the overall `Volume` of the brain, what sort of analysis can I perform to show if there is any relation to IQ and/or gender?

If the units don't matter, please explain why that is, when considering for example, that in an ANOVA/MANOVA, columns are summed and added to obtain `y..` (overall average). How would the `y..` result be acceptable considering that the columns are different units?

Comment: Would you agree that height and weight are related in adult human beings, with larger weights generally being associated with larger heights?  If so, you have implicitly determined an association among things with different units.  Why, then, should a difference of units in your ANOVA trouble you?

Answer (score 0):

As @whuber noted, the different units are not a problem. But the cross section of the corpus callosum might be colinear with the volume of the brain.  That would cause problems.

As to the type of analysis: If IQ is your dependent variable, then you could start with ordinary least squares regression, but if there is colinearity, you could try ridge regression or something else, depending on your exact goals.